# Cannot strip character using .strip() in python

Tags: python, strip, fasta

I am a biologist and need to make a quick script to process some files.

The file format is fasta:

```
>line1
ACCGAGCTACTAGXXXXX
>line2
ACGTAX
```

et cetera.

I want to remove all X characters and quickly put toghether this script:

```
print """Input file must be named FILE.fasta"""
fasta_file = raw_input('Input file name:') # Input fasta file
char = raw_input('Which sequence should be stripped?:')
OutFileName = fasta_file.strip('.fasta') + '_stripped.fasta'
OutFile = open(OutFileName, 'w')
WriteOutFile = True
data = open(fasta_file, "r")
for line in data:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        OutPut = line
    else:
        OutPut = line.strip(char)
        print OutPut
    OutFile.write(OutPut)
print(char)
OutFile.close()
quit()
```

It does not work and I can't figure out why. any help?

P.S. sorry for the terrible code.

Comment: What'snot working? _'Which sequence should be stripped?:'_

Comment: If I enter X as the char, it does not strip the X-es from the sequence lines.
So basically if I were to process the given example fasta file and define char as X, nothing would change in the output.

Comment: I used `strip` manually on both strings and it worked. Probably you also need to add `\n` to the strip list as all lines in the file end with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers specified better alternatives. But in your case, [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - str.**strip**(*[chars]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) didn't work because each line in a file ends with the *EOLN* terminator, so **X** is not actually at the end of the string.

The option that requires minimum of code changes, is to modify the 3<sup>rd</sup> line from:

```py
char = raw_input('Which sequence should be stripped?:')
```

to:

```py
char = raw_input('Which sequence should be stripped?:') + "\n"
```

**Beware**: the line `fasta_file.strip('.fasta')` might not do what you think it does. Here, it would be recommended to use:

```py
fasta_file.replace('.fasta', '_stripped.fasta')
```

***EDIT0***:

I think that you need to add the *EOLN* back when writing to the output file, so you also need to replace this line:

```py
OutPut = line.strip(char)
```

by:

```py
OutPut = line.strip(char) + "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick.
I know to look out for invisible characters from now on.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `line.replace(char,'')` instead `line.strip(char)`
Strip function removes characters only from sides https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using regex:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(\w[^X]+)")  # This groups everything but X
stripped = pattern.match(line).group()
```

For your case you can do something similar in the 'else' section of your code and replace the 'X' in "(\w[^X]+)" by your 'char' variable:

```
 pattern = re.compile("(\w[^" + char + "]+)")
```

Comment: For a simple task like this, regex is arguably overkill, and probably a significant additional hurdle on the learning curve for the OP.

Comment: agreed, I thought he was making incorrect use of the strip function but it turns out it was the "\n" at the end of the line that was the problem